# should + continous infinitive OR should + perfect continous infinitive

Tags: modal-verbs

I have been practicing grammar structures of various modal verbs (from the Thomson/Martinet structure drills exercise book) and I have come across this one exercise that left me pretty  confused.

The exercise is aimed at practicing two structures:

should + continuous infinitive (i.e. I should be doing)

and

should + continuous perfect infinitive (i.e. I should have been doing).

In the exercise, you are given 20 sentences and you have to transform them, using both structures—continuous inf. and perfect continuous inf. The example given made it pretty unclear for me when should I use which structure. It goes like this:

(ONE)

> A: It's 7.20 and Ann is sleeping.
>   B: She shouldn't be sleeping. She should have been getting dressed.

(TWO)

> A: At 7.20 yesterday Ann was sleeping.
>   B: She shouldn't have been sleeping. She should have been getting dressed.

So, my question is: Why is should + perfect continuous used in (ONE)?

In my understanding "should + continuous infinitive" would be the correct structure, as in:

"She shouldn`t be sleeping. She should be getting dressed (now)" ?

Is it an error / a typo or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations! You understand this too well to be intimidated by a textbook.

As it stands, the last sentence in ONE is probably in error; on the 'default' assumption that its reference is to Ann's current obligation, it should read

> A: It's 7.20 and Ann is sleeping.
>   B: She shouldn't be sleeping. She **should be** getting dressed.

However: if the sentence made an explicit reference to a past time, it would not be in error:

> She should have been getting dressed twenty minutes ago.

Comment: Like in: "Come on Joe, you`re still playing this computer game? You shouldn`t be doing that now! You should  be getting ready. Actually, you should have been getting ready like half an hour ago!!!" ??

Comment: @IGO Exactly. Move on to the next chapter, you've got this one nailed.

Comment: ok, back to obsessing about English tense system then. Cheers buddy ;)

Comment: I think I'd also use "should have been [...optional 'already']" to describe something that someone should be doing now and should have reached a state of progress consistent with having started some time ago, without reference to a specific amount of time. Or an implicit very recent time "should have been cleaning your room [five seconds ago when I opened the door and found you playing a video game, and starting now doesn't actually make up for that]"

Comment: @Random832 Ayup. Time reference with modals gets wonky cuz we got too many possibilities and too few forms to handle em.

Comment: @lrandom832, So you mean should + perf. continuous infinitive can be used to express an action in progress for some time up till now? Like in: "I have been cleaning this room for 20 minutes" "Good. Because that`s what you should have been doing. You should have been cleaning this bloody mess for 20 minutes [already] [now]." Is that what you meant?

Comment: @lrandom832: or perhaps you meant something like "Sweet Baby Jesus, you should have been painting this wall already" meaning "you should have started doing this already and be doing this now" ?

Comment: @IGO *Already* doesn't include the past in its reference, so it tends to take *should be*; but *You should have been painting the wall **by now*** is more natural.

Comment: @Araucaria A poignant reminder that dysfluency is universal.

Comment: @StoneyB Phew, I can upvote now I'm sure I understand properly!